# How to get current location continuously in the foreground in android using kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, locationmanager, foreground-service, currentlocation

I'm building an app the tracks the location of the device continuously, the location is only tracked when in the activity and stops when the activity is destroyed or closed.

How do I get the current location even if the app gets minimized and also display notification?

this is the activity that get the continuous current location.

```
import android.Manifest
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.location.Location
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices

class TestLocationActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
    private lateinit var locationRequest: LocationRequest
    private lateinit var locationCallback: LocationCallback
    private var locationListener: ((Location) -> Unit)? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_location)

        fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
        createLocationRequest()
        startLocationUpdates()
    }

    private fun createLocationRequest() {
        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create().apply {
            interval = 10000 // Update interval in milliseconds
            fastestInterval = 5000 // Fastest update interval in milliseconds
            priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    fun startLocationUpdates() {

        locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
            override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
                locationResult.lastLocation?.let { location ->
                    locationListener?.invoke(location)
                    Log.i("my location details", "${location.latitude},${location.longitude}")
                }
            }
        }
//        locationListener = listener
        if (hasLocationPermissions()) {
            fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(
                locationRequest,
                locationCallback,
                null
            )
        }
    }

    fun stopLocationUpdates() {
        fusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback)
    }

    private fun hasLocationPermissions(): Boolean {
        return ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this,
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
                ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }
}
```

I want to the app to get the current location continously even if the app gets minimized.